# Xcode 9.1 - Autolayout bug with "Align Horizontally"

Tags: ios, autolayout, xcode9.1

In my project, I have a XIB which contains a view with its hierarchy like this:

[image]

As you can see from the screenshot, my imageView is centered based on its superview, but visually it doesn't seem like so.

Further more, given the same view hierarchy and autolayout setup, whenever I change the alignment of the Label "Freelance Graphic Designer", the frame of the imageView jumps in a very weird manner:

[image]

Aside from this issue, I also encountered some others issues with my storyboards as well as XIB files.

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are the constraints of Rounded View?

Comment: Fully stretched to its superview. Turned out that the problem only occurs when a stackview presents. This is obviously a bug by Apple, I already fired a bug report and waiting for their response.

Comment: That is quite strange indeed. I recreated your layout on the side project and it looks as expected. Your center x constraint looks suspicious. Could you post the details of this constraint form the size inspector?